# Paypal: Recurring payments via Express Checkout without user having to have a paypal account

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, express-checkout

Currently I am using the express checkout API to create Recurring payments profile for paypal users, I was wondering if there was a way to allow users to still do this without having to own or create a paypal account?

It would instead ask for credit card information and create a profile that way?

Im currently passing these paramaters into my setExpressCheckout including my username, password and signature.

```
$nvpstr =   '&CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode(PAYPAL_CURRENCYCODE).
            '&PAYMENTACTION=Sale'.
            '&ALLOWNOTE=1'.
            '&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing'.
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode(PAYPAL_CURRENCYCODE).
            '&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0='.urlencode($itemname).
            '&VERSION='.urlencode(PAYPAL_VERSION).
            '&L_BILLINGTYPE0='.urlencode('RecurringPayments').
            '&RETURNURL='.urlencode(PAYPAL_RETURNURL ).
            '&NOTIFYURL='.urlencode(PAYPAL_NOTIFYURL ).
            '&NOSHIPPING='.urlencode(PAYPAL_NOSHIPPING ).
            '&CANCELURL='.urlencode(PAYPAL_CANCELURL);
```

Currently this is still asking users to create an account, any suggustions? Or is it that this does not work with recurring payments?

Comment: hav eyou implemented thi? I am asking as I have a quetion on how to pass the pricing and retrieve the token

Answer (score 0):

Pass SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in the initial SetExpressCheckout request

Comment: I tried that but it does not work, as well I checked whether the setting to have optional account was enabled